# Application Consent UI issue - Windows Phone Apps

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, marketplace

Last Week my team have submitted an application to Windows Phone Marketplace and in the end we got application failed because of the following issue
"**LOB App Compliance Requirements** - *Requirement*  is App capability consent UI is shown first on first launch of app - **Status** - Failed. *Tester given notes* **"No app capability consent UI is shown first on first launch of the app"**. Couldn't able to find out what was the exact error which made Application to fail in Marketplace. Does anyone came across such errors. Any feedback or suggestions will be useful for us.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a capability, when the user launch application, a pop up should appear for ask user for access.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Info. In That case if i am using Network capability and does i have to show a popup with allow or deny of accessing network capability. If so in this case if the user denies it what will be the scenario for the App.

Comment: For this case about NetWork Capability, just give user information if he is connected or not when application need to get data.